# Site GONE from webmaster tools. Cannot be scraped by google and fb. 500 error also

Tags: wordpress, facebook, google-search-console, internal-server-error

My website is [SWIMBIKERUN.ph](http://www.swimbikerun.ph/)

Hope you can really help me out with this one. Been working on this for over 3 weeks now and I just can't figure it out. Googled also everything.

For some reason, my wordpress website is emitting a 500 error. It just cannot be seen by Google webmaster tools or by facebook scraper.

The site is working fine on the surface, but it just cannot be crawled. I already fixed the robots.txt, sitemap, and even the htaccess.

The site was listed in google webmaster tools a couple of weeks ago. I was fixing the crawling issues etc and even had my site to work. The site suddenly had numerous crawl errors.

Now, my website is gone from GWT and I need to reverify my website to gwt but it's just not allowing me to do.

I tried everthing in GWT and did all the options to get my site verified. I even created a tag manager hoping it would work.

It's the same in facebook as well, when I scrape using debugger I get 500 error.

Weird because I thought this is because of my hosting (fatcow) but i also have two more sites (and online shop and a smf forum) also hosted and installed on the same server. Both are working flawlessly.  So it's gotta be something in wordpress. Analytics is working fine as well

Thank you

Comment: `but it's just not allowing me to do.` Does it give a message/error or what?

Comment: here's what it's saying :

GWT : We weren't able to verify your site: http://www.swimbikerun.ph/

Facebook : Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

I tried basically all options in GWT to get my site verified like html upload, html tag, google analytics, and even tab manager

Comment: Did you try verifying it with any of the other methods they have?

Comment: Yes. Everything is saying We weren't able to verify your site.

The outcome is either Verification failed. We were unable to connect to your server or Verification failed. Your verification file was not found

But if you check the source on my website, you will see all the required/needed files and codes there.

Comment: Is the robots.txt file any differently to the other websites that you have?

Comment: Hi. The robots.txt I believe is only for the main website of swimbikerun.ph